# UIWindow rootViewController couldn't find UIViewController subclass

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiwindow

I have a `CSRootViewController:UIViewController` without xib file, a `CSFirstViewController:CSRootViewController` with xib file. For bellow code I will get the error:

> "Application windows are expected to have a root view controller at
>   the end of application launch"

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

    CSFirstViewController *firstViewController = [[CSFirstViewController alloc] init];
    self.window.rootViewController = firstViewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

### update

Here is the `CSFirstViewController`'code. .h file:

```
@interface CSFirstViewController : CSRootViewController

@end
```

And the .m file

```
@interface CSFirstViewController ()

- (IBAction)pushButtonClicked:(id)sender;

@end

@implementation CSFirstViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil
{
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // Custom initialization
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - IBAction methods

- (IBAction)pushButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    CSSecondViewController *secondVC = [[CSSecondViewController alloc] init];
    [self.rootViewController pushCSViewController:secondVC animated:YES];
}

@end
```

Any guys could point me out the reason?

Comment: Can you please put CSFirstViewController .h & .m class...

Comment: You should log firstViewController to see if it's nil. I don't see anything else in this code that would cause the problem you're seeing.

Comment: Unless you overloaded CSFirstViewController init method you should use UIViewController's initWithNibName:bundle: method to init the root controller with xib file.

Comment: @V.J. Code you want to see is now added.

Comment: @rdelmar I have checked, it is not nil.

Comment: @yurish I have not overloaded that method and my root view controller does NOT have xib file.

Comment: you have extends CSRootViewController in CSFirstViewController. thats why you are facing this problem.. Once try UIViewController instead of  CSRootViewController.

Comment: @V.J. I want all my view controller has a root view controller so that I could do some thing to all. That is why.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find the way to handle my question. Just add `[self.window addSubview:firstViewController.view];` after set window's `rootViewController`. But I still don't know why this happens.